# Typescript file order issue when extending classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am defining models using TypeScript and I have encountered an issue when extending classes. I have two classes, each within a code file of the same name:

```
class kanine {
     name = 'dog'
}
```

and

```
class beagle extends kanine {
    constructor(name: string) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Within the solution they appear as such:

[image]

When I run the application I get this error:

[image]

However, when I rename the code file which contains the kanine class from kanine.ts to 1kanine.ts, I do not get the error. Another workaround is by bundling them like this:

```
.Include("~/app/kanine.js")
.Include("~/app/beagle.js")
```

Instead of like this:

```
.IncludeDirectory("~/app", "*.js")
```

Is there a way to process the files in an explicit order without having to include them individually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because the base class kanine needs to be defined before the parser gets to beagle.

You can fix this one of two ways:

1. Continue to explicitly define the order of each individual .js file as you are currently doing in your first example.
2. Change your compilation settings, either with a tsconfig.json or through the project properties, so that the .ts files are combined into a single .js file, and rely on the typescript compiler to order them properly.

If you choose option 2, you'll need to use /// reference tags to help the compiler figure out which file should be output first. This is as simple as adding this to beagle.ts:

```
/// <reference path="kanine.ts" />
```

This will make sure that kanines javascript is output before beagles.

Comment: I added ///<reference path="kanine.ts"/> to the beagle.ts file and I still get the "Uncaught" error. Is there some project level configuration which needs to be set to use those tags?

Comment: I suppose it might depend on how you are compiling the app. Is this an "HTML Application with TypeScript"? Do you have a tsconfig.json or did you go into the project properties and set the TypeScript build to "Combine JavaScript output into file:"?

Comment: I am not using a tsconfig.json file and I havn't changed any of the default settings in the TypeScript Build area of the web properties.

Comment: I see what's going on. You either need to explicitly define the order the dependencies as you have in the first example, or you need to combine these two ts files into a single file using a tsconfig or project properries and use the /// reference to define the order as I did in my example.

Comment: I edited my answer to more accurately reflect the solution.